# Why is cURL exec also returning the header data of my POST request?

Tags: php, curl

I'm just testing some code for image compression and then uploading to the Imgur API. But instead of just getting the response content I seem to be getting the header data as well and I can't figure out how to just parse the JSON. Here's what I have so far:

**compress_test.php**

```
include("imgur_upload.php");
echo compress_and_upload();
```

**imgur_upload.php**

```
function compress_and_upload(){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // for localhost
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE); // tried this but no change
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . IMGUR_CLIENT_ID));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => 'http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/51654499.png', 'type' => 'url'));

    $reply = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $reply;
}
```

What I'm expecting to be echoed is just the JSON data I believe.

**Here is what I'm getting:**

```
BHTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 03 Aug 2013 05:14:53 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 325
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: IMGURSESSION=dhjtli4c84koo2jbr8lild7ji7; path=/; domain=.imgur.com
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: _nc=1; path=/; domain=.imgur.com; httponly
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, Accept, X-Mashape-Authorization
X-RateLimit-ClientLimit: 12500
X-RateLimit-ClientRemaining: 12473
X-RateLimit-UserLimit: 500
X-RateLimit-UserRemaining: 497
X-RateLimit-UserReset: 1375510414
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Set-Cookie: UPSERVERID=i-614a2006; path=/
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Imgur-Cached: 0

{"data":{"id":"HE981gx","title":null,"description":null,"datetime":1375506893,"type":"image\/png","animated":false,"width":300,"height":300,"size":458117,"views":0,"bandwidth":0,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"deletehash":"qkl9lNDWCRR52Z0","link":"http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/HE981gx.png"},"success":true,"status":200}°
```

Comment: Are you sure that `CURLOPT_HEADER` isn't set somewhere?  What if you set it to `false`?

Comment: @Brad Yup, I tried it with `CURLOPT_HEADER` set to false but I'm still getting the entire thing so can't parse the JSON. I could find the first index of `{` but I really shouldn't have to.

Comment: @paranoid-android what version of php, what OS, and are you running this with the CLI or something like mod_php?

Comment: @Nirk PHP Version 5.4.12, Windows 7 x64. I'm running it how I always do just in browser using WAMP and I've never had this problem before.

Comment: @paranoid-android are errors treated the same way (try using an invalid ID)

Comment: @Nirk They are, for example the response string I get then starts with "`HTTP/1.1 403 Permission Denied". There's always a random character before and after the output.

Answer (score -2):

I ran the code on my own servers and used your code, didn't have this issue.

Comment: Did you go and register with them to get a client id? Because I definitely didn't share mine.

Comment: that has no relevancy. I think your server is not decoding the GZ encoding. I can tell by the character at the beginning and end of the result. I have been using CURL for years.

Comment: I think you're onto something but I have no idea how to go about enabling that or fixing this.

Comment: Try adding: curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');